# Select name if there is only one entry

Tags: php, sql

I want to select a name in SQL if there is only one entry in the table.
Something like

```
SELECT name
FROM stats
WHERE name =
  ( SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM stats WHERE COUNT(name) < 1
  )
```

I know this won't work, but how can I get this?

Comment: that sub query is finding when there are less than 1 results

Comment: @happymacarts no, [Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an opportunity!

SELECT name
FROM stats 
WHERE name in (SELECT s2.name
                   FROM stats s2
                   GROUP BY s2.name
                   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                  );

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT A.name 
FROM stats A
inner join (
SELECT count(*) `cnt`, name 
FROM stats 
group by name
) B on (A.name = B.name)
WHERE B.cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`HAVING`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)

```
SELECT `name` 
FROM `stats` 
WHERE `name` = (
    SELECT DISTINCT(`name`) 
    FROM `playerstats` 
    HAVING COUNT(`name`) = 1
)
```

If you're selecting from one table you do not need a nested query:

```
SELECT `name`
FROM `stats`
HAVING COUNT(`name`) = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, was my mistake. I've got an error in my code, it is edited above.

Comment: If you're selecting from the same table there is no need for a nested query.

Comment: It's saying Null, but there are some.